# Is there a non-alcoholic beverage that has bubbles like champagne?

Tags: carbonation

When drinking champagne, my favorite aspect of the drink, is the endless bubbles floating in tiny streams to the surface along the edge of a champagne flute.   I have very nice champagne flutes, but most sparkling fruit juices just don't have the same bubble action as any champagne.

Is there a non-alcoholic alternative to champagne, that has bubble action similar to champagne?

I ask, because I am physically unable to drink alcohol anymore.

Comment: here .. https://www.townandcountrymag.com/leisure/drinks/g21798734/non-alcoholic-champagne/

Comment: There are non-alcoholic sparkling wines.

Comment: It's not immediately clear, but have you tried the sparking juices in the champagne flutes? My understanding of the physics of bubbles is that they rely on nucleation points - the size of those points relates to how big the bubbles are. Champagne flutes have small nucleation points, so small bubbles

Answer (score 8):

Here, on the east coast of the US, there is a widely available, non-alcoholic, sparkling apple cider.  The producer is Martinelli & Co.

Comment: does it bubble like champagne?  I've tried other sparkling apple juices, and they don't have the same kind of bubbles.

Comment: Try sparkling grape juice. We always had it at Christmas dinner as kids, and it felt very grown-up, like drinking champagne. As an adult, I'm not sure how it would measure up compared to champagne. But I do think the flavor is better than sparkling apple cider.

Comment: @John When you've tried sparking apple juices, were they the kind that come in a champagne-style bottle? Those ones are designed to mimic champagne as closely as possible. They're easy to find in stores around Christmas and New Years, and nearly impossible to find at other times.

Comment: @John nothing sparkles like Champagne...but Martinelli's is inexpensive enough to give it a try.

Comment: Definitely this. My sister and brother in law don't drink alcohol for religious reasons, so we serve champagne for us and this sparkling cider for them. It tastes like a semi-dry apple juice, tbh, but it's about as bubbly as champagne though the bubbles are slightly larger and less tight. I've found it as far west as Denver, and there's also several varieties mixed with other fruits (which are weird and sweeter, imo.)

Comment: exists on the west coast too, widely available in supermarkets, same stuff.

Comment: In the US at least, there are the mentioned Martinelli sparkling ciders (multiple flavors) and Kedem sparkling grape juice, both at Costco (availability varies) and in grocery stores.  We use them for the fanciness factor, instead of alcoholic beverages.

Comment: FWIW:  I have tested the proposed solutions in the comments (and many others) and none of them came even remotely close to bubbling like champagne.